# Jenkins - backup jenkins_home directory safely

Tags: jenkins

I was wondering if it was safe compressing the Jenkins directory via:
`tar -zvcf /var/jenkins_home/`

Because what if there are race conditions?

Will the state of the `jenkins_home` that I compress into a tar.gz using the method above always be valid?

If so, then can you explain why it is valid? Because the tar.gz might happen during a critical Jenkins event.

Thank you.